# how to De-serialize a List<Generic<Enum>> using Gson library

Tags: java, json, gson, typetoken

I need to De-serialize this Json string into a POJO.

Json:

```
[
    {
        "first" : {
            "value" : 12,
            "suit" :  {
                "name" : "heart"
            }
        },

        "second" : {
            "value" : 12,
            "suit" : {
                "name" : "spade"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "first" : {
            "value" : 8,
            "suit" : {
                "name" : "club"
            }
        },
        "second" : {
            "value" : 9,
            "suit" : {
                "name" : "club"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to de-serialize this json string to a `ArrayList<Pair<Card>>` where the `Pair<?>` class is generic and the `Card` class is an enum.

I am attempting to do this via the following:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Pair<Card>>>(){}.getType();
List<Pair<Card>> handList = gson.fromJson(hands, listType);
```

Card class:

```
public enum Card {


@SerializedName("value")
public int value;
@SerializedName("suit")
public Suit suit;

Card(int value, Suit suit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
}
```

Suit class:

```
public enum Suit {


@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

Suit(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

However Gson keeps throwing `IllegalStateException`'s

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 3 column 15 path $[0].first
```

Comment: Because you're expecting a `String`, but you are being returned an object.

Comment: Yeah that really doesn't help however

Comment: Show us you `Card` class. And it match with `{ "value" : 9,"suit" : {"name" : "club"}}` this structure ?

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks edited my question with the Card and Suit enum classes

Comment: You don't define any enum inside enum class ?

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks how not? I define Suit enum property on a Card enum

Comment: @NateSchreiner I don't understand why you choose enum rather normal class? A enum class represents a group of constants which is missing in your class [Ex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks I omitted the constants becuase the list is 52 constants long for the Card, 4 long for suits

Comment: @NateSchreiner I also think that. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Deserializer for `Card` class

```
public class CardDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Card> {
    @Override
    public Card deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject jobject = obj.getAsJsonObject("suit");
        //Create Card here using those value
        //obj.get("value").getAsString();
        //jobject.get("name").getAsString();
        ...
        return card;
    }
}
```

And register in gson builder before work

```
gson.registerTypeAdapter(Card.class, new CardDeserializer());
```